# Wireshark Filter - Connect/Disconnect with no data sent

Tags: wireshark

How can I filter wireshark to show me when a client connects "SYN"/"SYN,ACK" and PSH,ACK == 0?
I'm trying to determine a list of clients where the client connects to the server and disconnects and no data is received.  I think I need to look at the tcp flags but not sure how to get my filter.  Wireshark wiki didn't help me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you want to trace connect/disconnect on port 22. Then your capture filter will be like this:

```
 "(port 22) && (tcp[0xd]&18=2 || tcp[0xd]&1=1)"
```

or with tshark:

```
tshark -f "(port 22) && (tcp[0xd]&18=2 || tcp[0xd]&1=1)"
```